# Eclipse Europa search references feature stopped working

Tags: eclipse, ide, menu, reference

I'm working with Eclipse Version 3.2.1 Build M20060921-0945 on a MS-Windows 2000 SP4 using a JDK 1.5.0-12.
I takes my locale that is es-AR and sets all menu and context in Spanish which I don't like. So I had included in eclipse.ini file one parameter *"-nl en"*.
Since that, *"References..."* feature in both *"Search"* and contextual menu stopped working. I removed parameter and ran eclipse with *"-clean"* but still not working. I don't have any other clue about what is happening. Thank you all in advance.
Beto

Answer (score 44):

Delete all the files in you eclipse data, eg:
`<WORKSPACE>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core`
This should force eclipse to rebuild its index

Comment: I didn't have the exact same scenario as the OP, i.e. I don't know what I changed that caused this to start happening, but I was having the same symptom.  This worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Any idea how you could prevent this problem in the future? I don't know why something of this nature would essentially "cache" itself anyways.

Comment: Wow, it worked for me for the same problem in Eclipse Oxygen. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't fix it in 2020-06 (4.16). Drives me NUCKING FUTS!

Answer (score 4):

I see a similar problem where search for references (Ctrl + Shift + G) stops working.  It works again if I **restart Eclipse**, but it's still pretty annoying.  I'm thinking maybe there's some keyboard shortcut that I hit sometimes by accident that messes up the search.

Comment: still having this problem. not sure how to resolve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same trouble with the latest Indigo release of Eclipse, searching for references of a method or class I selected invariably gave 0 results.

Stopping Eclipse, deleting all files in folder `<WORKSPACE>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core`, and restarting Eclipse afterwards has solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Go to {workspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.search and clear the History section of dialog_settings.xml , worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

After trying all of the above and nothing working, I took another look at the file name pattern I was using for file search:
*.java *.properties, *.vm, *.xml, *.xsd

I was missing the comma after *.java, so Eclipse wasn't searching my .java files, it was looking for files that matched the pattern "*.java *.properties".

Wow did I feel dumb dumb dumb... adding the comma fixed it! Passing along my simplistic solution in case it does anybody else some good...

Comment: [Search configuration window image here](http://subirfoto.es/2ro). Something like that happend to me. I just needed to put '*' on the File name patterns instead of what that was there before.

Answer (score 2):

Strange as it sounds, it does seem that the keyboard mapping affects this. I had mapped -H to Search in Files, and the Java search started bringing up everything, rather then actual references to the method I was searching for. ~Nothing~ fix this, including the solution above. But remapping the key to Open Search Dialog DID fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come to experience this behaviour with Eclipse Mars 1 Release 4.5.1.
In an specific class only. Clean and build entire workspace does not work but I've updated Maven Project containing that class [Right-click on project -> Maven -> Update Project ...] and it works now.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked for me. I thought I was going crazy. I am using Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

Answer (score 0):

I've just come to experience this behavior with Eclipse Mars 1 Release 4.5.1.

I tried everything mentioned above but it did not help.
So I created new workspace, and imported the project and search started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in Eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0) on Linux Mint

One thing that worked for me (besides closing and opening Eclipse again) was to click on the search icon and then in the **Show Previous Search** icon on the tab and then [Open in New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9KsW.png) :

Answer (score -1):

Trash your install.

Then reinstall it.

Comment: Don't do this. Use Ferry's solution. Not only is this a waste of time, but it may not even work considering that trashing your install doesn't actually delete the index files as they are located in the workspace directory.