# Ctrl+Shift+G no longer works in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a huge fan off *Eclipse* hotkeys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> being one of my favorite.  However, I recently had to completely toss out my workspace and load a new one to switch to a new branch after some merge-cause had occured.  Either that, or a later checkin which messed with some classpath files, seems to have broken my ability to search using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  I now always find nothing.

I have multiple maven projects which all link to each other, and I thought the issue originally was with maven.  However, I can't even find methods in the same project, or even the exact same file, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> now.

Can anyone suggest the process I take to make my eclipse aware of my source code such that it can properly search it?

EDIT:
I don't know how I missed this previously.  It seems that eclipse is throwing a class-not-found exception looking for the class

```
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.dbt.core.project utils
```

Before this exception is thrown I can do search as normal, after this exception the search breaks.  So the issue is actually the exception i'm sure.  A reboot does fix things temporarily, Unfortunately, the exception keeps getting thrown after I use eclipse for awhile.  So now I'm looking into the cause of the exception.  I may post an answer here and/or open a new question depending on how much luck I have researching the cause of the exception on my own.

Comment: So is the shortcut just not working? If you go to `Preferences > General > Keys` and search for "References in Workspace" is nothing showing up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctrl + Shift + R is not working in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725587/ctrl-shift-r-is-not-working-in-eclipse)

Comment: I like Ctrl + o and Ctrl + Shift + R much better

Comment: My edit above already addressed msot of this.  but search runs, it just doesn't return any hits when it should.  Also the link above doesn't apply to my situation, which is caused by an exception.

Comment: For my case, this solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648360/2667768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Preferences dialog. (On Windows, choose the menu item *Window>Preferences*).

Choose the preferences page *General>Keys*.

Navigate down to the command *References in Workspace*. Select it. If the displayed binding is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, you can set it by:

- Pressing the desired key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- Pressing the *Apply* or *OK* button.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update on this issue.  Once I realized the exception was the cause of my issue I researched it on *Stack Overflow*.  I found another question that addressed the issue, though I'm afraid I don't have the link now.  The suggested answer though was to start *Eclipse* with the `--clean` option.  The issue appears to have gone away as soon as I did this.

I have upvoated both the other answers as thank-you for you responses.  They were good answers given the information I original provided, it was my fault I wasn't aware of the full issue when I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

i believe maybe your hotkey was unprogramed somehow, try readding it

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Mac: Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Hope this helps